# Redirecting new tab OR browser on button click.(Response.Redirect) in asp.net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

Can anybody suggest how we can open the page in new window or New Browser using Response.Redirect in c#.
I have used :
Response.Redirect("page1a.aspx");

but it's open in existing tab.

Comment: I can't see how this makes sense.  If you're redirecting from the server to a new window, what loads in the first window?  Nothing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can you use javascript if yes then please try this

```
        Response.Write("<script>");
        Response.Write("window.open('ClickPicture.aspx','_blank')");
        Response.Write("</script>");
```

Comment: @ArvindSSalunke will it be fine if the page is opened in new tab

Comment: @ArvindSSalunke I edited my answer please try that and let me know if that works